# jQuery - on button click, emulate input[type="file"].change only in parent element

Tags: jquery, file, types, input, input-type-file

I am not sure if title says what correctly I am trying to do but I don't know how to name that problem.

I am trying to add some style to input[type="file"] element using css and jquery. Here is my code:

```
<div class="input-file">
    <input type="file"><label>Select file...</label><button type="button">...</button>
    </div>
```

where INPUT has display: none style so it's not visible.

Javascript:

```
$('.input-file > button').live('click',function() {
$('input[type="file"]').click(); });
```

It works good if only 1 element is on page but if there are for example 3, whenever I click on button 1, it will fire function 3 times. I would like it to respond only for it's parent element which is `<div class="input-file">`

How could I use .parent or .before or whatever function can work to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

@Chandu has a great solution.

Also, another alternative would be $(this).prev().prev().click(); if elements are static and always in the same position.

Thank you @Chandu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.input-file > button').live('click',function() {
    $(this).closest('.input-file').find('input[type="file"]').click(); 
});
```

**Update:**
If you are using jquery >= 1.7 then use this version with `on`:

```
$('.input-file').on('click', 'button',function() {
    $(this).closest('.input-file').find('input[type="file"]').click(); 
});
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I also found another solution and I will post it in first post.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btn-upload').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#file').click();
        });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #file { display:none; } 
</style>

<div>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <button type="button" id="btn-upload">Image</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can olso use **label** tag for emulate click. label tag emulate click input of current form with id like **for** attribute.
Examle:

```
<label for="file-input">
    Click me!
    <input type="file" id="file-input" style="display:none;" />
</label>
```